# Android Showing and hiding view on user interaction

Tags: android, android-layout

I have map and some views on it. I would like to make some views disapearing when there is no user interaction (no touch, no click on map) and when interaction is detected then I would like to show a view, like with default zoomControls on android google map. How could I do it ? Anybody can help I would be thankful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t use TimerTask. That runs a separate thread, but in Android you are only allowed to make UI calls from the UI (main) thread.

Instead, in your Activity, create yourself a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). You can then use its postAtTime or postDelayed methods to queue runnables that will run at (approximately) the specified time on the UI thread. These runnables are free to make UI calls.

Comment: Couple more points:  Every View has a Handler of its own, so you can post directly to the view and save yourself the trouble of defining a Handler.  You can also use Activity.runOnUiThread()